# Program used to find the HexCode of a given color

Tags: colors, hexadecimal

I was wondering if there is a program that could take a color that you have, and return the hex code for it.

I have been trying to match the color against samples online but still haven't found the correct code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://instant-eyedropper.com/

Sounds like just what you need.

Alternatively, the eyedropper tool of pretty much any graphic design software such as Illustrator and Photoshop does just that.

Answer (score 0):

If the color isn't already in an image, take a picture of it with a scanner or digital camera. Then open the image with any application that has a color picker. I like [Paint.NET](http://paint.net/).

If you're using Paint.NET, select `Color Picker` from the `Tool` drop down. Then open the `Colors` window by hitting `F8` (or finding it in the menu). Click on `More`. Move the `Colors` window so you can see it, but you can also get to the part of the image that has the color you're interested in.
Now you can left-click anywhere on the image and the line labeled `Hex` on the right side of the `Colors` window will show you the hex code for that color.

You can even hold the left mouse button down and the hex code will update as you move around the image.

Comment: Maybe not quite as slick, but Microsoft Paint has a similar capability.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this all the time for web development:
[ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorzilla/)